# Disabling automatic footnotes in Emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, source-code, code

I have some LaTeX inside an org-mode file that is wrapping a Ruby code snippet and providing nice color formatting, which looks kind of like this:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{listings}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \lstloadlanguages{Ruby}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \lstset{%
#+LATEX_HEADER: basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
#+LATEX_HEADER: commentstyle = \ttfamily\color{red},
#+LATEX_HEADER: keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue},
#+LATEX_HEADER: stringstyle=\color{orange}}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Ruby]
pairs_list.each {|pair|
    if (pair[0]-pair[1]).magnitude < min_dist
        min_dist = (pair[0]-pair[1]).magnitude
        best_pair = pair
    end
  }
\end{lstlisting}
```

All of this works fine except for the square brackets in the array addressing, which are erroneously identified as org footnotes. I tried setting `autofn:nil` in options, tried adding `#+STARTUP: nofninline, noautofn` and refreshing, but nothing worked. org-mode tries to export the nonexistent footnotes and makes a bunch of garbage.

What's the easiest way to turn this off on a per-file basis?

edit: The reason why you would bother doing this instead of #+BEGIN_SRC #+END_SRC is because that format is uglier and does not include colors (although that may hint at a way to solve it).

Comment: Note that `\[ \]` doesn't work because the code environment prints backslashes.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137769/escaping-org-mode-footnote-like-text) solves the problem on a per-character basis, but not a per-file basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported in [this mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-08/msg00490.html), the way to stop org-mode from trying to parse the LaTeX block is to put `#+BEGIN_LATEX` `#+END_LATEX` wrappers around it. This will get you proper (LaTeX) export behavior while ensuring it is interpreted only as LaTeX.